# Why 2 methods to submit forms?

Tags: forms, mobile, buttons, user-expectation, ios

Why do we give users a 'Log in' button when they can submit the form via keyboard?

I know when I search the ios App Store, the only way to submit the form is with the keyboard. Should the same be done when users are creating accounts or logging in?

Just for example, log out of instagram. Enter your username and password. You can log in by pressing 'go' on the keyboard, or by pressing the 'Login' button the page. Why 2 options?

Answer (score 1):

Idk if I did anything special here, but my login form has no buttons :)

https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/jWMwzy

A lot of improving the user experience is approaching it behaviorally. If it's easier to log in by having a button in two spots, why not? Some people are used to using the button on their mobile screen's keyboard, but other people maybe be using a desktop computer. Someone who is using a mobile phone might be more familiar with desktops, and therefor uses the screen to push the "submit" button. A good book recommendation is "Don't Make me Think" by Steve Krug. We try to make things easier, which in this case (surprisingly) means not simpler but adding elements.

Comment: I understand your answer. I just noticed when responding to your answer there is no 'submit' button on the page. I have to press 'send' on the ios keyboard.